# Returning multiple GUID’s from a text string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I haven’t written SQL queries in almost 2 decades, so I’m a bit rusty.  My database has a text field that stores somewhat unstructured data like the following:

```
{"title":"MyDashboardTitle","layoutValue":"50%50%_100%","layout":[{"columns":[{"dashletsIds":[0,1],"class":"column percents50 ui-sortable"},{"dashletsIds":[2,3],"class":"column percents50 ui-sortable"}]},{"columns":[{"dashletsIds":[4,5],"class":"column percents100 ui-sortable"}]}],"dashlets":[{"data":{"dataSourceId":"efe860e8-7e7f-414d-bc7d-
 86dacf0cb352","chartType":"mscolumn3d","labelsColumn":"Description","height":"350","captionModified":true,"chart":{"items":{"theme":"default","bgColor":"#ffffff","rowsToDisplay":"100","caption":"Top 10 Customers Potentially Impacted by Vulnerabilities","bgAlpha":"100","animation":"1","subCaption":"","numberPrefix":"","showLegend":"0","showValues":"1","showLabels":"1","xAxisName":"","yAxisName":""},"counter":13},"values":[{"aggregation":8,"value":"High Risk","toolText":""},{"aggregation":8,"value":"Medium Risk","toolText":""}],"colorRanges":
[{"valueFrom":0,"valueTo":25,"color":"#008000"},{"valueFrom":25,"valueTo":50,"color":"#ffff00"},{"valueFrom":50,"valueTo":75,"color":"#ffa500"},{"valueFrom":75,"valueTo":100,"color":"#ff0000"}],"colorPoints":[{"color":"#ffff00","label":"Low","value":0},
{"color":"#008000","label":"High","value":100000}]},"title":"","dashletClass":"chart"},{"data":{"dataSourceId":"e9716f7b-d2f7-4b69-b652-46a2a869663f","chartType":"mscolumn3d","labelsColumn":"Device Category","height":"350","captionModified":true,"chart":{"items":{"theme":"default","bgColor":"#ffffff","rowsToDisplay":"100","caption":"Vulnerabilities by Device 
Category","bgAlpha":"100","animation":"1","subCaption":"","numberPrefix":"","showLegend":"1","showValues":"1","showLabels":"1","xAxisName":"","yAxisName":""},"counter":13},"values":[{"aggregation":8,"value":"High Risk","toolText":""},{"aggregation":8,"value":"Medium Risk","toolText":""},{"aggregation":8,"value":"Low Risk","toolText":""}],"colorRanges":[{"valueFrom":0,"valueTo":25,"color":"#008000"},{"valueFrom":25,"valueTo":50,"color":"#ffff00"},{"valueFrom":50,"valueTo":75,"color":"#ffa500"},{"valueFrom":75,"valueTo":100,"color":"#ff0000"}],"colorPoints":[{"color":"#ffff00","label":"Low","value":0},
{"color":"#008000","label":"High","value":100000}]},"title":"","dashletClass":"chart"},{"data":{"dataSourceId":"786f8c08-98f7-435c-ae61-c15697f4d51b","chartType":"mscolumn3d","labelsColumn":"System Name","height":"350","captionModified":true,"chart":{"items":{"theme":"default","bgColor":"#ffffff","rowsToDisplay":"100","caption":"Vulnerabilities by 
System","bgAlpha":"100","animation":"1","subCaption":"","numberPrefix":"","showLegend":"1","showValues":"1","showLabels":"1","xAxisName":"","yAxisName":""},"counter":13},"values":[{"aggregation":8,"value":"High Risk Vulnerabilities","toolText":""},{"aggregation":8,"value":"Medium Risk Vulnerabilities","toolText":""}],"colorRanges":[{"valueFrom":0,"valueTo":25,"color":"#008000"},{"valueFrom":25,"valueTo":50,"color":"#ffff00"},{"valueFrom":50,"valueTo":75,"color":"#ffa500"},{"valueFrom":75,"valueTo":100,"color":"#ff0000"}],"colorPoints":[{"color":"#ffff00","label":"Low","value":0},
{"color":"#008000","label":"High","value":100000}]},"title":"","dashletClass":"chart"},{"data":{"dataSourceId":"344c64ab-27e3-4e73-b76b-15d08d6cde66","chartType":"msbar3d","labelsColumn":"Business Function","height":"350","captionModified":true,"chart":{"items":{"theme":"default","bgColor":"#ffffff","rowsToDisplay":"100","caption":"Business Function Vulnerability 
Impact","bgAlpha":"100","animation":"1","subCaption":"Ordered by Business Function Priority","numberPrefix":"","showLegend":"1","showValues":"0","showLabels":"1","xAxisName":"","yAxisName":""},"counter":13},"values":[{"aggregation":8,"value":"High Risk Count","toolText":""},{"aggregation":8,"value":"Medium Risk Count","toolText":""}],"colorRanges":[{"valueFrom":0,"valueTo":25,"color":"#008000"},{"valueFrom":25,"valueTo":50,"color":"#ffff00"},{"valueFrom":50,"valueTo":75,"color":"#ffa500"},{"valueFrom":75,"valueTo":100,"color":"#ff0000"}],"colorPoints":[{"color":"#ffff00","label":"Low","value":0},
{"color":"#008000","label":"High","value":100000}]},"title":"","dashletClass":"chart"},{"data":{"dataSourceId":"b2c30000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","chartType":"pareto3d","labelsColumn":"Product","height":"350","captionModified":true,"chart":{"items":{"theme":"default","bgColor":"#ffffff","rowsToDisplay":"100","caption":"Software Vulnerabilities","bgAlpha":"100","animation":"1","subCaption":"by Software and Version","numberPrefix":"","showLegend":"0","showValues":"0","showLabels":"1","xAxisName":"","yAxisName":""},"counter":13},"values":[{"aggregation":8,"value":"count","toolText":""}],"colorRanges":[{"valueFrom":0,"valueTo":25,"color":"#008000"},{"valueFrom":25,"valueTo":50,"color":"#ffff00"},{"valueFrom":50,"valueTo":75,"color":"#ffa500"},{"valueFrom":75,"valueTo":100,"color":"#ff0000"}],"colorPoints":[{"color":"#ffff00","label":"Low","value":0},{"color":"#008000","label":"High","value":100000}]},"title":"","dashletClass":"chart"},{"data":{"dataSourceId":"58346380-8bee-4838-91a4-80400352031a","labelsColumn":"label","height":"","captionModified":false,"chart":{"items":
{"height":"","rowsToDisplay":"1000","caption":null,"animation":null,"bgColor":"#ffffff","showAllColumns":"0"},"counter":6},"values":[{"value":"System Name","toolText":""},{"value":"Asset Name","toolText":""},{"value":"CVEScore","toolText":""},{"value":"MfgName","toolText":""},{"value":"ProdName","toolText":""},{"value":"Version","toolText":""},{"value":"Summary","toolText":""}]},"title":"Vulnerabiliites List","dashletClass":"table"}],"filters":[]}
```

Although there is some formatting to the data, it isn’t CSV’s or anything highly structured like that, and each field will have unique formatting.

I’m trying to return all of the `datasourceID`’s.  My guess is that I’ll need to use a recursive function and search for the ‘`datasourceID`:’ `String`, then grab the next 36 characters.  I can figure out how to do this for the first occurrence, but can’t figure out how to search for the next occurrences.

Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: It's look like JSON format. SQL Server 2016 and above support JSON parsing functions. Please google it.

Comment: And on earlier versions, think CLR where you can also work with JSON. trying to do this in just T-SQL is going to be a bad idea given it's poor support for string manipulation.

Comment: Thanks!  It has been long enough that I didn’t recognize the format!